# ¿Como calcular el tramo mas largo dentro de un grupo y saber su identificacion en SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla en el que constan dentro de cada grupo, unos tramos de rios, quiero saber para cada grupo el tramo mas largo, y su identificador.

[image: Tabla]

Consigo saber para cada grupo el tramo mas largo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando quiero que me indique su identificador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dice que el identificador (iden) ha de estar en una clausula de agrupación.

Este es el resultado que quiero conseguir:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ni siquiera se, si es posible, pero cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y si haces un `Count` y luego lo ordenas de mayor a menor?

Comment: naaa @fredyfx, con funciones ventanas o un join se arregla... tendrias que ordenar tambien por funciones ventana para que funcione...ç

Comment: Ideas.. no tengo tiempo de darte una respuesta completa.. Usa un join con la misma tabla para agregar la columna que falta, joinea por longitud grupo (ojo, que pasa si tenes dos iguales?) o usa una funcion ventana (para ordenar y obtener el mayor)

Comment: @gbianchi zaaaapeee!

Comment: Hola por favor cambia la pregunta, a texto para darte mi respuesta, es un poco mas facil de la mostrada y podras aprender un poco mas de el motor de PSQL => https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/em7kvGGyVEgiagPguAiqUY/0

Comment: puedes eliminar la imagen de la consulta SQL y agregar el codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer eso con un CTE o una tabla derivada, ayudado de la función `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
-- Ejemplo con CTE
WITH cte_Iden AS( 
    SELECT Grupo,
        iden,
        longitud,
        -- Generamos una columna con números ordenados por la longitud que se reinician en cada grupo.
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Grupo ORDER BY longitud DESC) rn
    FROM Tabla_Iden
)
SELECT Grupo,
       iden,
       longitud
FROM cte_Iden
WHERE rn = 1; --Seleccionamos solo la primera fila de cada grupo (la longitud mayor)

-- Ejemplo con tabla derivada
SELECT Grupo,
       iden,
       longitud
FROM (
    SELECT Grupo,
        iden,
        longitud,
        -- Generamos una columna con números ordenados por la longitud que se reinician en cada grupo.
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Grupo ORDER BY longitud DESC) rn
    FROM Tabla_Iden
)t
WHERE rn = 1; --Seleccionamos solo la primera fila de cada grupo (la longitud mayor)
```

Como podras obserbar la implementacion de `ROW_NUMBER()` nos ha ayudado a conseguir los registros necesarios, es importante conocer que:

> Numera la salida de un conjunto de resultados. Más específicamente,
> devuelve el número secuencial de una fila dentro de una partición de
> un conjunto de resultados, comenzando en 1 para la primera fila de
> cada partición.
>
> `ROW_NUMBER` y `RANK` son similares. `ROW_NUMBER` numera todas las
> filas secuencialmente (por ejemplo, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). `RANK` proporciona
> el mismo valor numérico para empates (por ejemplo, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5).

Documentación asociada: [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)

Comment: Pero mejor se lo explicas, que tuve que leerlo dos veces para entenderlo...

Comment: si respondiste la pregunta, es porque te parecio interesante, que tal si valoras la pregunta, asi como otros lo hicieron con ru respuesta

Comment: Perfecto, eso me da el resultado esperado, muchisimas gracias por vuestra ayuda, espero seguir mejorando ya que veo que me falta mucho por aprender.